# Failed to read key androidDebugKey from store <key>: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Tags: android, flutter, android-keystore, android-app-signing

This is a Flutter project.

I have generated a keystore file using this command:

`keytool -genkey -v -keystore path\signInDebug.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias androidDebugKey`

Then I have placed this key in my app folder `android\app` in my flutter project.

I have then added this config in my `android/app/build.gradle`

```
signingConfigs{
        debug{
            keyAlias 'androidDebugKey'
            keyPassword '<password>'
            storeFile file('signInDebug.jks')
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
```

Now when I try to run my app I'm getting this error:

```
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key androidDebugKey from store "pathToProject\android\app\signInDebug.jks": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

I'm sure that the password and the alias I'm putting is correct.
I'm following this tutorial [Youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5WgU6ERZzA&t=474s&ab_channel=JohannesMilke)

Answer (score 1):

Silly mistake, I forgot the `storePassword` property.